# Spring Boot jdbc template and mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

i'm new to Spring Boot so you may say i'm a newbie, so these last few days i've been working on the mongoDB database , so my problem is that i want to use the JDBC template on MongoDB using sts spring boot , i don't know really were to start , is it possible to work with mongoDB and jdbc template ? because i used it on an oracle database?
can you please guys guide me or suggest something , thanks for your help.

Comment: For MongoDB, you can use MongoTemplate. It provides a rich set of methods for MongoDB collections. You can use MongoRepositories but I personally feel it is not helpful beyond basic CRUD operations.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in spring-boot I would prefer to use the `Repository` instead doing stuff via the template.
You should start reading here:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

You could use `MongoTemplate` but the common way is to extend `MongoRepository`

Comment: thnak you bro that was helpful, can i retrieve data from mongo database without creating the entity ?